# Pause/resume video recording with AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, video-capture

I am using AVFoundation framework for video recording. I need to implement the functionality to pause the recording and user can also resume it. I searched alot but couldn't find any material.

One idea I have in mind is to call the following method to pause the recording without closing the session :

```
[outputfile stopRecording];
```

and for resuming I should call:

`startRecordingToOutputFileURL:fileURL recordingDelegate:self];`

But after doing this the following delegate method is never called:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
      fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
```

Is there any other way to pause/resume video recording?

Answer (score 0):

I made it by stopping the recording when user presses "Pause" and write a file to documents directory. When user presses "Resume", I start recording in a new file. At the end I combine all these in a single file. And cleanup at the end.

Comment: Can you post sample code?  Or give more detail to your statement "I combine all these in a single file".  Thanks